# How to add FK to existingTable?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

How can I add fk to the field img for table message, that i get the image-name automaticlly from table user ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
If my understanding is correct.  You have UserTable built as Above.

A single user has a SINGLE image.. IF the user changes their Image, you want that tied to each message.

Building on those assumptions MessageTable should have these 3 columns only  Assuming this is where you store your "messages"

id_mesg, fk_userId, MessageText.

Then the following Statement will give you the updated image every time it is run...

```
SELECT  mt.id_msg, mt.MessageText, ut.img, ut.uname
FROM UessageTable mt
JOIN UserTable ut
    On ut.id_user= mt.fk_userId
```

Remove the img column and uname column entirely from the message-table..   They are not needed.

Comment: I prefer to use Foreign Key in user-Table. 
Yes, every img in Message table exists in Table User. the FK should be the alternative solution.

Comment: I'm having a hard time translating exactly what you're after.   To many pieces of information in your head that you are not getting established into your question correctly.  Please Clarify both OP and comment.

Comment: at the moment, when i create a new row in table Message, i just copy the image name from the table (user). but the problem, if the user changes his image, so the image in table Message will not be updated.  so I have to conect the table message with table user using fk.

Comment: So is it accurate to say, that id_user has a 1 to 1 relationship with img?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this works in mysql but an idea in sql

```
 ALTER TABLE message-table ADD CONSTRAINT fk-message-img FOREIGN KEY 
 (img)
     REFERENCES user_table(id_user);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alter Table statement over here.

ALTER TABLE message-table ADD CONSTRAINT user_img
FOREIGN KEY ( img ) REFERENCES user-table ( img ) ON DELETE  ON UPDATE ;

for your use-case you can use cascade option which will let the changes flow from user-table to message table

Also If the user to image mapping is 1:1 then you should not be duplicating img in message-table. Rather, just keep the uName of user-table and join on that column while reading.